# Newbie at TimelineMax and ScrollMagic

Tags: animation, css-animations, scrollmagic, gsap

I am trying my hand at using one of Petr Tichy's templates after taking a few of his courses.  I do fine for awhile but then like this I hit a wall and I am not sure what I did wrong.

The website page goes along smoothly until the 3rd scene (which starts at "**var pinScene03Tl**" in the code) then all animation after that does not work or show it is applying to the content at all when you view it in the inspector. I have rechecked the html and the code over and over again.

The code to the animation website is very long as well as but I will post the main.js which is my timelineMax and scrollMagic js.

MAIN.JS

```
(function ($) {

// Init ScrollMagic
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// get all slides
var slides = ["#slide01", "#slide02", "#slide03", "#slide04", "#slide05"];

// get all headers in slides that trigger animation
var headers = ["#slide01 header", "#slide02 header", "#slide03 header", "#slide04 header", "#slide05 header"];

// get all break up sections
var breakSections = ["#cb01", "#cb02", "#cb03", "#cb04", "#cb05"];

// number of loaded images for preloader progress 
var loadedCount = 0; //current number of images loaded
var imagesToLoad = $('.bcg').length; //number of slides with .bcg container
var loadingProgress = 0; //timeline progress - starts at 0

$('.bcg').imagesLoaded({
    background: true
  }
).progress( function( instance, image ) {
    loadProgress();
});

function loadProgress(imgLoad, image)
{
    //one more image has been loaded
    loadedCount++;

    loadingProgress = (loadedCount/imagesToLoad);

    //console.log(loadingProgress);

    // GSAP timeline for our progress bar
    TweenLite.to(progressTl, 0.7, {progress:loadingProgress, ease:Linear.easeNone});

}

//progress animation instance. the instance's time is irrelevant, can be anything but 0 to void  immediate render
var progressTl = new TimelineMax({paused:true,onUpdate:progressUpdate,onComplete:loadComplete});

progressTl
    //tween the progress bar width
    .to($('.progress span'), 1, {width:100, ease:Linear.easeNone});

//as the progress bar witdh updates and grows we put the precentage loaded in the screen
function progressUpdate()
{
    //the percentage loaded based on the tween's progress
    loadingProgress = Math.round(progressTl.progress() * 100);
    //we put the percentage in the screen
    $(".txt-perc").text(loadingProgress + '%');

}

function loadComplete() {

    // preloader out
    var preloaderOutTl = new TimelineMax();

    preloaderOutTl
        .to($('.progress'), 0.3, {y: 100, autoAlpha: 0, ease:Back.easeIn})
        .to($('.txt-perc'), 0.3, {y: 100, autoAlpha: 0, ease:Back.easeIn}, 0.1)
        .set($('body'), {className: '-=is-loading'})
        .set($('#intro'), {className: '+=is-loaded'})
        .to($('#preloader'), 0.7, {yPercent: 100, ease:Power4.easeInOut})
        .set($('#preloader'), {className: '+=is-hidden'})
        .fromTo($('#intro .title'), 1, {rotation:180, scale:0.5, autoAlpha: 0}, {rotation:0, scale:1, autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.2')
        .from($('.scroll-hint'), 0.3, {y: -20, autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '+=0.1');

    return preloaderOutTl;
}

// Enable ScrollMagic only for desktop, disable on touch and mobile devices
if (!Modernizr.touch) {

    // SCENE 1
    // create scenes for each of the headers
    headers.forEach(function (header, index) {

        // number for highlighting scenes
        var num = index+1;

        // make scene
        var headerScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: header, // trigger CSS animation when header is in the middle of the viewport 
            offset: -95 // offset triggers the animation 95 earlier then middle of the viewport, adjust to your liking
        })
        .setClassToggle('#slide0'+num, 'is-active') // set class to active slide
        //.addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin), use for debugging
        .addTo(controller);
    });

    // SCENE 2
    // change color of the nav for dark content blocks
    breakSections.forEach(function (breakSection, index) {

        // number for highlighting scenes
        var breakID = $(breakSection).attr('id');

        // make scene
        var breakScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: breakSection, // trigger CSS animation when header is in the middle of the viewport 
            triggerHook: 0.75
        })
        .setClassToggle('#'+breakID, 'is-active') // set class to active slide
        .on("enter", function (event) {
            $('nav').attr('class','is-light');
        })
        .addTo(controller);
    });

    // SCENE 3
    // change color of the nav back to dark
    slides.forEach(function (slide, index) {

        var slideScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: slide // trigger CSS animation when header is in the middle of the viewport
        })
        .on("enter", function (event) {
            $('nav').removeAttr('class');
        })
        .addTo(controller);
    });

    // SCENE 4 - parallax effect on each of the slides with bcg
    // move bcg container when slide gets into the view
    slides.forEach(function (slide, index) {

        var $bcg = $(slide).find('.bcg');

        var slideParallaxScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: slide, 
            triggerHook: 1,
            duration: "100%"
        })
        .setTween(TweenMax.from($bcg, 1, {y: '-40%', autoAlpha: 0.3, ease:Power0.easeNone}))
        .addTo(controller);
    });

    // SCENE 5 - parallax effect on the intro slide
    // move bcg container when intro gets out of the the view

    var introTl = new TimelineMax();

    introTl
        .to($('#intro header, .scroll-hint'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone})
        //.to($('#intro .bcg'), 1.4, {y: '20%', ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.2')
        .to($('#intro'), 0.7, {autoAlpha: 0.5, ease:Power1.easeNone}, 0);

    var introScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#intro', 
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: "100%"
    })
    .setTween(introTl)
    .addTo(controller);

    // SCENE 1915 - pin the first section
    // and update text

    var pinScene01Tl = new TimelineMax();

    pinScene01Tl
        .fromTo($('#slide01 .slideLeft'), 0.6, {autoAlpha:0}, {left:70, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide01 .slideRight'), 0.6, {autoAlpha:0}, {right:80, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('.slideLeft .caption'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=0.8')
        .to($('.slideRight .caption'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=0.8')
        .fromTo($('.slideLeft .caption'), 0.7, {y: '+=20'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '+=0.4')
        .fromTo($('.slideRight .caption'), 0.6, {y: '+=20'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide01 .quotebuttonL'), 0.2, {autoAlpha:0}, {left:30, top:50, rotation:360, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide01 .quotebuttonR'), 0.2, {autoAlpha:0}, {right:30, top:50, rotation:360, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide01 .videobuttonM'), 0.2, {autoAlpha:0}, {top:100, rotation:360, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide01 .textbuttonM'), 0.2, {autoAlpha:0}, {top:200, rotation:360, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide01 .cstone1915'), 1, {autoAlpha:0,}, {right:0, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '+=1')
        .to($('#slide01 .quotebuttonL'), 0.2, {left:500, top:150, autoAlpha:0, rotation:360, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('#slide01 .quotebuttonR'), 0.2, {right:500, top:150, autoAlpha:0, rotation:360, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('#slide01 .videobuttonM'), 0.2, {top:150, autoAlpha:0, rotation:360, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('#slide01 .textbuttonM'), 0.2, {top:150, autoAlpha:0, rotation:360, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('#slide01 .slideLeft'), 0.2, {left:0, autoAlpha:0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('#slide01 .slideRight'), 0.2, {right:0, autoAlpha:0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('.slideLeft .caption'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=0.8')
        .to($('.slideRight .caption'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=0.8')
        .to($('#slide01 .cs1915'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=0.8')
        .fromTo($('#slide01 .cs1915'), 0.7, {y: '+=60'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '+=0.4')
        .set($('#slide01 h1'), {autoAlpha: 1}, '+=2');

    var pinScene01 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#slide01', 
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: "250%"
    })
    .setPin("#slide01")
    .setTween(pinScene01Tl)
    .addTo(controller);

    // SCENE 1917 - pin the second section
    // and update text

    var pinScene02Tl = new TimelineMax();

    pinScene02Tl
        .fromTo($('#slide02 h1'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0}, {autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=1.5')
        .to($('#slide02 section'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeNone}, 1.5)
        .to($('#slide02 .bcg'), 0.6, {scale: 1.2, transformOrigin: '0% 0%', ease:Power0.easeNone})
        .fromTo($('#slide02 h1'), 0.7, {y: '+=20'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '+=0.4')
        .fromTo($('#slide02 section'), 0.6, {y: '+=20'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .set($('#slide02 h1'), {autoAlpha: 0}, '+=2.5');

    var pinScene02 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#slide02', 
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: "125%"
    })
    .setPin("#slide02")
    .setTween(pinScene02Tl)
    .addTo(controller);

     // SCENE 1918 - pin the second section
    // 

   var pinScene03Tl = new TimelineMax();

    pinScene03Tl
        .fromTo($('#slide03 h1'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0}, {autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=1.5')
        .to($('#slide03 section'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeNone}, 1.5)
        .to($('#slide03 .captionMain'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide03 h1'), 0.7, {y: '+=20'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '+=0.4')
        .fromTo($('#slide03 section'), 0.6, {y: '+=20'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .set($('#slide03 h1'), {autoAlpha: 1}, '+=2.5');

    var pinScene03 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#slide03', 
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: "125%"
    })
    .setPin("#slide03")
    .setTween(pinScene03Tl)
    .addTo(controller);

         // SCENE 1921 - pin the second section
    // 

   var pinScene04Tl = new TimelineMax();

    pinScene04Tl
         .fromTo($('#slide04 h1'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0}, {autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=1.5')
        .to($('#slide04 section'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeNone}, 1.5)
        .fromTo($('#slide04 .slideLeft'), 0.6, {autoAlpha:0}, {left:70, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide04 .slideRight'), 0.6, {autoAlpha:0}, {right:80, autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('#slide04 .slideLeft'), 0.2, {left:0, autoAlpha:0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('#slide04 .slideRight'), 0.2, {right:0, autoAlpha:0, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .set($('#slide04 h1'), {autoAlpha: 1}, '+=2.5');

    var pinScene04 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#slide04', 
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: "200%"
    })
    .setPin("#slide04")
    .setTween(pinScene04Tl)
    .addTo(controller);

         // SCENE 1922 - pin the second section
    // 

   var pinScene05Tl = new TimelineMax();

    pinScene05Tl
        .to($('#slide05 h1'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=0.6')
        .to($('#slide05 section'), 0.2, {autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power1.easeNone}, '-=0.6')
        .fromTo($('#slide05 h1'), 0.7, {y: '+=20'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '+=0.4')
        .fromTo($('#slide05 section'), 0.6, {y: '+=20'}, {y: 0, autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power1.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
        .set($('#slide05 h1'), {autoAlpha: 1}, '+=2.5');

    var pinScene05 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: '#slide05', 
        triggerHook: 0,
        duration: "125%"
    })
    .setPin("#slide05")
    .setTween(pinScene05Tl)
    .addTo(controller);

    // change behaviour of controller to animate scroll instead of jump
    controller.scrollTo(function (newpos) {
        TweenMax.to(window, 1, {scrollTo: {y: newpos}, ease:Power1.easeInOut});
    });

    //  bind scroll to anchor links
    $(document).on("click", "a[href^='#']", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("href");
        if ($(id).length > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // trigger scroll
            controller.scrollTo(id);

                // if supported by the browser we can even update the URL.
            if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
                history.pushState("", document.title, id);
            }
        }
    });

}

}(jQuery));
```

[You can see the whole thing in action here](http://www.justawebbie.com/centennial/index.html). I am really trying to learn this and need help in debugging it so I can keep building it out to a nice timeline using best practices. I want to learn how to do this and really could use the help. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: I solved this by starting all over and all I can say it must have been an errant semi-colon or comma.